# Sequelize literal field in where cluse

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this situation:

```
const sells = await Sell.findAll({
  order: [['created_at', 'desc']],
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [
        Sequelize.literal(
          `(SELECT "transaction_status" FROM "sell_status" AS "StatusTable" WHERE "StatusTable"."sell_id" = "Sell"."id" ORDER BY "StatusTable"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1)`
        ),
        'current_status',
      ],
    ],
  },
});
```

and when I try to access the field inside the clause where the answer is:

"column Sell.current_status does not exist"

can someone help me?

Comment: What DB do you use? Add a tag indicating it

Comment: Postgres my friend, excuse me! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `sell_status` table is exist in the db?

Comment: Please add model definition to your post

Comment: sell_status exists and the relation between tables is Sell have many SellStatus, I used a subquery to get the last status of an sell, I need to include this subquery results in the clause where.